# How to use class from other files in C# with visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am a newbie to C# and *MS Visual Studio*, and I want to use the C# class which is defined in another file, but can't get it to work.

Here is the `program.cs`(and why can't I rename that file ?)

```
using System;

namespace TestCSharp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Class2 class2 = new Class2();
            //Here the IDE will complain that can't find namespace or balabala..
            class2.setValue(10);
            Console.WriteLine(class2.getValue().ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the `Class2` that I want to use in file `Class2.cs`:

```
namespace TestCSharp2
{
    class Class2
    {
        int i;
        public void setValue(int i)
        {
            this.i = i;
        }
        public int getValue()
        {
            return this.i;
        }
    }
}
```

Should I `#include` or something? isn't `use namespace` enough?

[image]

---

As some guys asked if they were *in the same assembly/same project*, I **presume** they were, because here is the procedure for how they are created:

- A new project using the template of *Console C# Project*, then the `program.cs` was created by default.
- The Class2.cs was created with [File] -> [New] -> [File] -> [C# class] and saved in the same folder where `program.cs` lives.

To be honest, I don't know if they are in *same assembly* / *same project*, but I guess they were.

Comment: Do they both lives in same assembly? Also prefer using Properties over get/set methods. C# isn't java :)

Comment: are they in the same project? so that when they are compiled they end up in the same binary?  If they are in separate projects, then you need to make the first project reference the 2nd.

Comment: Thanks for your advice about getter/setter, but I don't know what do you mean by *the same assembly*.

Comment: @armnotstrong I mean same project. Are they defined in same project? Not same solution, but project.

Comment: Thing is you haven't inlcude the class2 in your porject. simple as that :)

Comment: @KcDoD I just edited the question about how these two files was created, hope they are in same project, but can't be sure :(

Comment: simply right click on you project -> Add - > Existing Item : Select Class2.Cs

Answer (score 35, accepted):

According to your explanation you haven't included your `Class2.cs` in your project. You have just created the required Class file but haven't included that in the project.

> The Class2.cs was created with [File] -> [New] -> [File] -> [C# class] and saved in the same folder where program.cs lives.

Do the following to overcome this,

Simply `Right click` on your project then  -> [Add] - > [Existing Item...] : Select `Class2.cs` and press OK

Problem should be solved now.

Furthermore, when adding new classes use this procedure,

`Right click` on project -> [Add] -> Select Required Item (ex - A class, Form etc.)

Comment: Thanks for help, but is there a better way to create a file that by default it belong to the same project, referencing it every time I create a a file is not a good way, I think.

Comment: Latter part of my answer provide that information :) .. Regards

Comment: Thanks again, I think it's the project navigator in the right rather than the left which differs from formerly IDEs I used that why I negligence it :-)

Answer (score 13):

Yeah, I just made the same 'noob' error and found this thread.
I had in fact added the class to the solution and not to the project.
So it looked like this:

[image: Wrong and right description]

Just adding this in the hope to be of help to someone.

Answer (score 5):

It would be more beneficial for us if we could see the actual *project structure*, as the classes alone do not say that much.

Assuming that both .cs files are in the same project (if they are in different projects inside the same solution, you'd have to add a reference to the project containing Class2.cs), you can click on the `Class2` occurrence in your code that is underlined in red and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> (period) or click on the blue bar that should be there. The first option appearing will then add the appropriate `using` statement automatically. If there is no such menu, it may indicate that there is something wrong with the project structure or a reference missing.

You could try making `Class2` `public`, but it sounds like this can't be a problem here, since by default what you did is `internal class Class2` and thus `Class2` should be accessible if both are living in the same project/assembly. If you are referencing a different assembly or project wherein `Class2` is contained, you have to make it `public` in order to access it, as `internal` classes can't be accessed from outside their assembly.

As for renaming: You can click `Program.cs` in the Solution Explorer and press F2 to rename it. It will then open up a dialog window asking you if the class `Program` itself and all references thereof should be renamed as well, which is usually what you want. Or you could just rename the class `Program` in the declaration and again open up the menu with the small blue bar (or, again, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>) and do the same, but it won't automatically rename the actual *file* accordingly.

**Edit after your question edit:** I have never used this option you used, but from quick checking I think that it's really not inside the same project then. Do the following when adding new classes to a project: In the Solution Explorer, right click the project you created and select [Add] -> [Class] or [Add] -> [New Item...] and then select 'Class'. This will automatically make the new class part of the project and thus the assembly (the assembly is basically the 'end product' after building the project). For me, there is also the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> working to create a new class.

Comment: How can I add the nice 'button' graphics for keyboard shortcuts again? I always forget...

Answer (score 4):

```
namespace TestCSharp2
{
    **public** class Class2
    {
        int i;
        public void setValue(int i)
        {
            this.i = i;
        }
        public int getValue()
        {
        return this.i;
        }
    }
}
```

Add the 'Public' declaration before 'class Class2'.

Comment: By default, classes in namespace are public, if the access mofidifier wasn't specified. So no need to add that. Just like members in class are private by default, it don't specify the access modifier.

Answer (score 2):

According to your example here it seems that they both reside in the same namespace. I conclude that they are both part of the same project (if you haven't created another project with the same namespace)
and all classes by default are defined as internal to the project they are defined in, if haven't declared otherwise, therefore I guess the problem is that your file is not included in your project.

You can include it by right clicking the file in the solution explorer window => Include in project, if you cannot see the file inside the project files in the solution explorer then click the show the upper menu button of the solution explorer called show all files (just hover your mouse cursor over the button there and you'll see the names of the buttons).

**Just for basic knowledge:**
If the file resides in a different project\ assembly then it has to be defined,
otherwise it has to be defined at least as internal or public.

In case your class is inheriting from that class that it can be protected as well.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem here. Found out that the problem was with an Advanced Property of the file. There is there an option with the name 'Compilation Action' (may be not with the exact words, I am translating - my VS is in Portuguese).

My Class1.cs file was there as "Content" and I just had to change it to "Compile" to make it work, and have the classes recognized by the others files in the same project.

Comment: I had this too; I had copied some code files into a project, and their "Build Action" (English) had been set to Content, and their classes could not be found by other code files until I changed it to "Compile".

Answer (score -1):

Just make two projects in two different files then rename the "Program.cs" of one of the two files
and copy it then paste it next to the Program.cs of the other file and that's it.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

In your project there will be a file with `.csproj` extension.

Double click on it to open the project in the Visual Studio. Otherwise, if you make a new class, it won't link with other classes.

Answer (score -3):

When u diclare your , var
you , can use private , declarasion

using System;
private Class class;

Comment: How it is helpful?

Comment: This is not only incorrect—a `private` class can't be referenced by other classes—but it also doesn't provide any real acknowledgment of the specifics of the question. Can you please review the question and the existing answers, and then reevaluate your answer accordingly?