# Visual Studio Code cant find class

Tags: c#, class, visual-studio-code

Hey Im very new to C# so in my Programming course the teacher creats a new class.
This wasnt working in my Version of VS Code so i createt a new File and Named it Human.cs
But in the Main-Methode it cant resolve the class.
Heres my Code:

```
using System;

namespace Udemy_21
{
   class Program
   {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // Create Obejekt Human Class

        Human human = new Human();

        

        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
     }
   }
}
```

The second code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Udemy_21
{
    // Blaupause für Datentyp
    class Human
    {
    // Membervariable: Vorname
    public string firstname;

    // Member Methode
    public void IntroduceMyself() 
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Hi ich bin, {0}", firstname);
    }
  }
}
```

An heres a picture of VS code:

[VS Code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPfwv.jpg)

Comment: Try making the class Human a public class.

Comment: @TerryTyson This should make no difference as long as both classes are in the same project (assembly)

Comment: @SchnellfeuerXD, @ Klaus Gütter is right. For now, you could just put your Human class in the same file as the Program class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you need to include the class. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28449564/how-to-use-class-from-other-files-in-c-sharp-with-visual-studio) to a very similar question and see if it works for you.
You also should use Visual Studio when working with C#.

Comment: Thanks there was an answer that helped me!

Comment: I'm a bit late, but I'm glad it could help you!